# Evolution dismissed as "less secure app" by Google

Tags: evolution, contacts, google-calendar

I know this issue has been discussed countless times before, but I am still baffled. I have tried switching to Evolution many times, and setting up the Google email and calendar account, looks so straight forward, yet no go, Google just keeps asking for password again and again (And yes, I have enabled imap forwarding.) 
I am using Ubuntu 16.04. 
I downloaded Evolution 3.15.5 from the repositories.
I downloaded syncevolution, likewise from repositories (v. 1.05)
I was denied access to my google contacts and calendar (receiving the usual apologetic mail from Google today.) 
I see there are a lot of people on the net saying they have no problem. But I cannot fathom what they are doing (apart from enabling "less secure apps"). The following link seems very detailed: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution/synchronize-google-contacts-with-evolution-addressbooks, but it is far too (!) complicated. Could somebody please spell it out for me. 
I do really wish to switch to Evolution.

Comment: In 16.10 you can add google contacts directly without going through oauth or syncevolution setup. For evolution works just fine with 16.04. I don't use two-factor authentication as I use oauth (online accounts from Unity-Control-Center) for contacts and calendar. For mail always use IMAP with evolution.

Answer (score 1):

I have second factor auth turned on on my google account. I ran into this problem with Thunderbird and posted on gmail forums, but the answer turned out to be simple. Try using an app-specific password, if you are already using app-specific passwords, then make sure you type your standard password correctly. For me, it was just the fact that I needed to type my actual password in, and not use a generated one when I was trying to use a generated one without typing in my regular password first.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. It makes sense to use a second (generated) password, but it would be very inconvenient for me, as I log in and out maybe 20 times a day.   Surely, there must be another solution?

Comment: I agree, that would be inconvenient to have to type the randomly generated password every day. The purpose of these is to enter into a program such as an email client to save the password so only that application can store the password securely and access the account. Are you unable to save the randomly generated app specific password in evolution, or are you able to save it and the application is still asking for your password periodically?